# How to disable options button functionality when video playing in bright script

Tags: android, ios, roku, brightscript

I am working on roku using Scene Graph. I want disable options(asterisk) button functionality when video playing.
Thank you.

Comment: Seen also at https://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=96315 - but give it a week or two for response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentations the video player will ALWAYS have the options button functionality when in full screen,

> "The one exception is the closed-caption dialog, which always appears when the video is playing fullscreen."

from: https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Video

What I did is actually set the video to be 1px less than full screen (e,g 1280 x 719), and then I was able to capture and override the options key functionality. It might be possible to add a 1px transparent rectangle on the video instead.